# Calling WSL bash.exe from C#

Tags: c#, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Mostly just as a curiosity, I wrote a little app to start up Terminator shell on Windows, using Ubuntu/WSL and Xming window server.

Doing things manually from the shell, I can run Firefox, gedit, Terminator, etc on Windows, it's pretty cool.

So I checked the location of `bash.exe` using `where bash` and it returned...

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
```

However when I tried to run this code...

```
using (var xminProc = new Process())
{
    xminProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe";
    xminProc.StartInfo.Arguments = ":0 -clipboard -multiwindow";
    xminProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    xminProc.Start();
}
using (var bashProc = new Process())
{
    bashProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe";
    bashProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \"export DISPLAY=:0; terminator; \"";
    bashProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    bashProc.Start();
}
```

I get the error...

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'
```

And checking my entire system for `bash.exe` reveals it really be in another place altogether...

[image: bash.exe location]

I'm not sure if this location is one that I can rely on, I'm worried it's ephemeral and can change during a Windows Store update, although I may be wrong about that.

Why does the command prompt show `bash.exe` to be in `System32` but it's really in another location altogether?

Can I get C# to also use the `System32` location?

Comment: Set the soultion platform as x64. And use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` to get System32 folder.

Comment: 32-bit programs will be put under [File system redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector) so you can't see the real system32 folder using the path `C:\Windows\System32`

Answer (score 6):

As @Biswapriyo stated first set the platafrom to x64 on your solution:

[image]

Then you may run on your ubuntu machine from c# as:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter command to execute on your Ubuntu GNU/Linux");
            var commandToExecute = Console.ReadLine();

            // if command is null use 'ifconfig' for demo purposes
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(commandToExecute))
            {
                commandToExecute = "ifconfig";
            }


            // Execute wsl command:
            using (var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = @"cmd.exe",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            })
            {
                proc.Start();
                proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("wsl " + commandToExecute);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); // give some time for command to execute
                proc.StandardInput.Flush();
                proc.StandardInput.Close();
                proc.WaitForExit(5000); // wait up to 5 seconds for command to execute
                Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you.  For new browsers: Don't assume your machine in compiling to 64bit because it will waste half your day like it did mine, if you do.